Audio Issues on Lenovo ThinkPad T16 with Ubuntu 24.04.1LTS
I'm experiencing audio issues on my Lenovo ThinkPad T16 running Ubuntu 24.04. The audio device is detected correctly, and I can adjust the volume, but I’m not hearing any sound, not even system sounds or audio played through aplay.
Here's what I've tried so far without success:

I verified that all audio channels are unmuted and at an audible level.

I tested sound output using the command aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav, but there still is no sound.

I checked audio settings in the system settings, and everything looks normal.


Are there any additional troubleshooting steps specific to Lenovo T16 models or general Ubuntu audio issues that I should try?
$ lspci -nnk |grep -A3 -i aud

00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS [8086:51ca] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS [17aa:2310]
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller [8086:51a3] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller [17aa:230e]

